# How to connect a mDP Mini Display Port 4K 60Hz / 30 Hz output from a Tablet PC to a new Portable 13 or 15" 2K/ 3K/ 4K Display with only USB-C support?

Tags: external-display, usb-c, mini-displayport

How to connect a mDP Mini Display Port 4K 60Hz / 30 Hz output from a Tablet PC to a Portable 13 or 15" 2K/ 3K/ 4K Display with only USB-C support?

I have a Surface Pro 3 and our family has 2 more S Pro 4 and 5.

Typically we used to use mDP to DP or mDP to HDMI adapters etc. Here I am wondering whats possibly a way to do this?

I am wondering how their output could be connected to such a portable monitor/ display?

Comment: I believe that you need a cable or adapter to accomplish this.  Would [this](https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-Certified-Gold-Plated-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B07RY75V7Q/ref=asc_df_B07RY75V7Q/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=344022943810&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17105539184288365979&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9051880&hvtargid=pla-836958607167&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=69534739336&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=344022943810&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17105539184288365979&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9051880&hvtargid=pla-836958607167) not do the trick?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes. But USB-C to DP is easy and common, other way around is not

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Saw your comment before sleeping and did not check link. Will do. Just saw. No it won’t. It’s C to DP not mDP to C

Comment: Bummer.. sorry man.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about bi-directional stuff but did not find a concrete article on this matter until this - and I will update this answer as I find and learn more on the subject of evolving HDMI/ DP / USB-C and related Display connectivity.

Sometimes the best answers are harder to come by on a Google Search and never show up until you dig, or stumble randomly upon them on the web.

Here's a detailed and elaborate answer from Dan Charlton's Tech Blog, "[Bi-directional USB-C -> DisplayPort & HDMI cables](https://dancharblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/10/bi-directional-usbc-dp-cables/)":

> Bi-directional USB-C DisplayPort cables monitor, USB-C   1 Comment
>
> May 10, 2020
>
> If you search Amazon or another major retailer for USB-C ->
> DisplayPort adapters, there are dozens to choose from. >99% are single
> direction with the source/host PC intended to be connected via USB-C
> and the destination/monitor to be connected with DisplayPort.
>
> What if you need to go the other way? For example, suppose you have a
> USB-C-only monitor. How do you connect that to a PC that only has
> DisplayPort?
>
> Get the right cable that supports bi-directional or reverse signaling.
> These cables are considerably more expensive than typical cables since
> they have several integrated circuits inside to handle both
> directions.
>
> For example, the StarTech cables combine a Via VL170, a Chrontel
> CH7213C, and a TI TUSB544.
>
> DP 1.4 CABLES/ADAPTERS (FULL SIZE DP)
>
> With DP 1.4 / HBR3 support, these are the most capable and
> future-proof offerings:
>
> Club 3D CAC-1557 8K60 (2m length) (~$35)   Infinnet 8K-ready (2m
> length) (~$40)   Infinnet 8K-ready (0.5m length) (~$30)   Moshi
> 99MO084102 5K60 (1.5m length) (~$45)   Startech CDP2DP141MBD 8K30 (1m
> length) (~$37)   Startech CDP2DP142MBD 8K30 (2m length) (~$40)
>
> DP 1.2 CABLES/ADAPTERS (FULL SIZE DP)
>
> AmazonBasics UTC-DP-B-L (1m or 2m lengths) (~$16)   Startech
> CDP2DP1MBD 4K60 (1m length) (~$33)   Startech CDP2DP2MBD 4K60 (2m
> length) (~$33)   VisionTek 901288 (2m length) (~$30)
>
> SINGLE DIRECTION (REVERSE) ONLY:
>
> DeLock DP -> USB-C adapter 63928 (~$30) (20cm length)   Belkin cable
> for Huawei VR (~$95) (DP + 2x USB-A -> USB-C)
>
> WHAT ABOUT MINIDP?
>
> Some laptops like Surface only have a miniDP receptacle. The simplest
> approach for these is to use a MiniDP->DP adapter in series with one
> of the full-size DP cables as follows:
>
> [PC] –> [MiniDP->DP adapter] –> [DP->USB-C cable] –> [USB-C monitor]
>
> In general, multiple adapters/cables in series is not recommend for
> inaccessible or mission-critical systems. But for most home users this
> will be just fine.
>
> Another approach is this Wacom device:
>
> Wacom Link adapter ACK42719 (~$60) (mDP + USB 2.0 -> USB-C)
>
> WHAT ABOUT HDMI?
>
> Several brands offer HDMI -> USB-C or HDMI -> DP cables but they are
> single-direction aka “reverse” only:
>
> Wacom Link Plus adapter ACK42819 (~$75) (single direction only)   ..
> combines miniDisplayPort or HDMI + USB 2.0 into USB-C   Generic ebay
> cable HDMI + USB 2.0 -> USB-C (~$50) (single-direction only)
> Visiontek 900822 HDMI -> DP ($35) (single direction only)   Cable
> Matters 103069 HDMI -> DP ($35) (single direction only)   .. HDMI->DP
> with USB power

RESOURCES:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/lg-ultrafine-4k-yes-you-can-connect-it-to-windows-computers-via-dp.2227756/

Answer (score 0):

Use an active bidirectional cable like this https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HLR62ZM/A/moshi-usb-c-to-displayport-cable and a mini dp to dp adapter. This assumes the display is not powered by usb-c